# SystemName returning blank

Tags: powershell, wmi

I have a Powershell script that runs everyday at a set time to return some ShadowCopy statics. For some reason one of your servers is returning a blank system name when ran under the command:

```
GWMI Win32_Volume | Select SystemName
```

The computer does have a set name like the others in the script. I was wondering if anyone knows a way to set this property name on the computer environment.

Comment: `echo $env:computername` isnt enough ?

Comment: Have you tried the `__SERVER` property?

Comment: Check and see if the dotnet / WMF version on that server isn't downlevel from the rest.

Comment: or `$x = hostname` (calling hostname.exe). You might try running a WMI diagnostic ( http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff404265.aspx ) or rebuilding the WMI repository ( http://blogs.technet.com/b/askperf/archive/2009/04/13/wmi-rebuilding-the-wmi-repository.aspx ).

Answer (score 1):

Use one of the alternative properties `__Server` or `PSComputerName`. Either should get you the result you want.

Comment: I tried both properties and for some reason it is breaking the script. I will post the script so you guys can see what environment I am working with.